# Multiple lines in Google Charts with different number of datasets

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts, google-visualization

In Google Charts I want to display 3 different lines. But they do not have the same number of data points.

The following Image was made with Excel Chart, so that you can understand my problem better.

Line grey has only two data points, the orange line goes until 5 and the blue one has full data set.

So now to my real project:
in Google Chart I tried the same, so my dataArray looks like that (with 4 lines):

```
["20180629", 24.5, 28, 27.52, 24.6],
["20180630", 23, 28, 23.57, 24.4],
["20180701", 22.6, 26, 23, 23.5],
["20180702", 23, 25, 22.44, 23.5],
["20180703", 25.1, 28, 24.43, 26.3],
["20180704", 27.6, 30, 24.59, 21.4],
["20180705", 28.9, 24.1, 23.8, ],
["20180706", 24.4, , , ],
["20180707", 23.7, , , ],
["20180708", 24.8, , , ]
```

So you can see, that from 20180629 to 20180704 there is the full data set, in 20180705 is one missing and in 20180707 and 20180708 are 3 missing.

It is no opportunity, to display a 0 there, because this would show wrong temperature charts.

The Chrome Console shows this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Row given with size different than 5 (the number of columns in the table).
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `null` in place of the empty data points...

```
["20180629", 24.5, 28, 27.52, 24.6],
["20180630", 23, 28, 23.57, 24.4],
["20180701", 22.6, 26, 23, 23.5],
["20180702", 23, 25, 22.44, 23.5],
["20180703", 25.1, 28, 24.43, 26.3],
["20180704", 27.6, 30, 24.59, 21.4],
["20180705", 28.9, 24.1, 23.8, null],
["20180706", 24.4, null, null, null],
["20180707", 23.7, null, null, null],
["20180708", 24.8, null, null, null]
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["20180629", 24.5, 28, 27.52, 24.6],
    ["20180630", 23, 28, 23.57, 24.4],
    ["20180701", 22.6, 26, 23, 23.5],
    ["20180702", 23, 25, 22.44, 23.5],
    ["20180703", 25.1, 28, 24.43, 26.3],
    ["20180704", 27.6, 30, 24.59, 21.4],
    ["20180705", 28.9, 24.1, 23.8, null],
    ["20180706", 24.4, null, null, null],
    ["20180707", 23.7, null, null, null],
    ["20180708", 24.8, null, null, null]
  ], true);

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Yes it was my intention. And it works! Thank you so much! I tried different things, but I did not get that an INT can also be NULL. So thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks.