# Multiple data set to google charts

Tags: php, charts

I have 1 data table consisting of 2 data sets, but could be more.  Typically the data is :-

```
var ar = [[["09:17:39",-23.4],["09:17:59",-23.4],["09:18:19",-23.4]],[["00:00:44",12.8],["00:01:05",12.8],["00:01:26",12.8]]].
```

The simple data set has 2 columns `time` & `value`.

The code that I have is :-

```
var ar = <?php echo json_encode($TopArray, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) ?>; 
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Time');
data.addColumn('number', 'value');
    data.addRows(ar);

    var options = {'title' : 'Something',
            hAxis: {title: 'Time'},
            vAxis: {title: 'Value'},                
           'width': 1200,
           'height': 600,              
        };

var chart = new 
google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

What is wrong with this code ? 
If someone can help it would be gratefully appreciated - Thanks

Comment: I don't see any line of PHP code. Only JavaScript.

Comment: If something is wrong with your script, your question should describe it to US.

Comment: This looks like something that would have come up while you were researching: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41767578/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/51106238/2943403